# When developing a database, is it important to keep in mind a future application?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am in the process of designing a database for the first time outside of the classroom in order to make a future java application work with complete desired functionality. As I am trying to design entity relationship diagrams and tables, I find myself always thinking about my java project that is required later. I am beginning to wonder if this is making me more confused and if I am making this more difficult for myself; I am beginning to get nervous that I might not be skilled enough yet to pull this off.

Should I just focus on producing the most normalized database I can and trust that it will allow for my application to do everything it needs to do?

Or,

Should I definitely be keeping my future application in mind with each step of database development to ensure total functionality?

**Edit**: I would also appreciate any recommendations on free database design tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are notoriously hard to refactor, so if you know about something you haven't gotten to yet but are definitely going to do, you need to consider that in your design.  This is espcially true if the future something (For example reporting) is going to need to look at lots of records or is going to need moment in time data as opposed to doing calculations on the fly. This is the difference between storing the cost of an order vice calculating it based on current prices for instance. If you just look at the order process, you may thing it is ok to just calculate the price, but reporting will need to know what the price was at the time the order happened or the financial records will be messed up.

You might read this:
[What are the general guidelines and best practices to keep in mind while designing database for an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568580/what-are-the-general-guidelines-and-best-practices-to-keep-in-mind-while-designi/1568814#1568814)

Comment: thanks @HLGEM, I didn't see that question post before I posted mine. It helped out a lot.